# `Let` inference in Hindley-Milner

Tags: haskell, clojure, hindley-milner

I am trying to teach myself Hindley-Milner type inference by implementing Algorithm W in the language I usually use, Clojure. I am running into an issue with `let` inference, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if the result I'm expecting requires something outside of the algorithm.

Basically, using Haskell notation, if I try to infer the type of this:

```
\a -> let b = a in b + 1
```

I get this:

```
Num a => t -> a
```

But I should get this:

```
Num a => a -> a
```

Again, I'm actually doing this in Clojure, but I don't believe the problem is Clojure-specific, so I'm using Haskell notation to make it clearer.  When I do try it in Haskell, I get the expected result.

Anyway, I can solve that particular problem by converting every `let` into a function application, for example:

```
 \a -> (\b -> b + 1) a
```

But then I lose `let` polymorphism.  Since I don't have any prior knowledge of HM, my question is whether I am missing something here, or if this is just the way the algorithm works.

**EDIT**

In case anyone has a similar issue and wonders how I solved it, I was following [Algorith W Step By Step](https://github.com/wh5a/Algorithm-W-Step-By-Step/blob/master/AlgorithmW.pdf).  At the bottom of Page 2, it says "It will occasionally be useful to extend the *Types* methods to lists." Since it didn't sound mandatory to me, I decided to skip that part and revisit it later.

I then translated the `ftv` function for `TypeEnv` directly into Clojure as follows: `(ftv (vals env))`. Since I had implemented `ftv` as a `cond` form and didn't have a clause for `seq`s, it simply returned `nil` for `(vals env)`.  This of course is exactly the kind of bug that a static type system is designed to catch!  Anyway, I just redefined the clause in `ftv` pertaining to the `env` map as `(reduce set/union #{} (map ftv (vals env)))` and it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's wrong, but I'd guess your let-generalization is wrong.

Let's type the term manually.

```
\a -> let b = a in b + 1
```

First, we associate `a` with a fresh type variable, say `a :: t0`.

Then we type `b = a`. We get `b :: t0` as well.

However, and this is the key point, we should *not* generalize the type of `b` to `b :: forall t0. t0`. This is because we can only generalize over a tyvar which does not occur in the environment: here, instead, we do have `t0` in the environment since `a :: t0` is there.

If you do generalize it, you will get a way too general type for `b`. then `b+1` becomes `b+1 :: forall t0. Num t0 => t0`, and the whole term gets `forall t0 t1. Num t1 => t0 -> t1` since the types for `a` and `b` are unrelated (`t0`, once generalized, can be alpha-converted to `t1`).

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. The problem was in how I was handling the free type variables in the environment. Thanks!